# Conditions for equilibrium on a hexagonal pencil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, centripetal-force, statics

[A hexagonal pencil lies on a
slope with inclination angle α; the angle
between the pencil’s axis and the line of
intersection of the slope and the horizontal
is φ. Under what condition will the pencil
not roll down?](https://www.ioc.ee/%7Ekalda/ipho/meh_ENG.pdf)

[image]

The solution says $$cos(\phi) tan(\alpha) < tan(\frac{\pi}{6})$$

And the hints point toward 3D coordinates but I am not at all familiar with 3D equations. I've only been able to form this equation so far.  $$\mu > tan(\alpha)$$to prevent sliding of the pencil.

EDIT: I made progress.

First, if I break it down to 2 components, I get that [image] and further [image]
But how should I derive the inequality with this?

Comment: hey Ayaan, Check for unstable equilibrium

Answer (score 1):

Since the pencil is in equilibrium, the frictional force is equal to the component of gravitational force along the slope. Take a component of that force along the perpendicular to the pencil, and balance the torques due to gravity, normal force, and friction. For the borderline case, the normal force must be acting at the edge of the pencil. You'll get the answer after balancing the torques.

Note: Assume the coefficient of friction is large enough.

Comment: I got the $\mu <= tan(\theta)$ wrong. It should instead be $\mu > tan(\theta)$. I have made the necessary corrections.